# JS files in dist folder throwing compile time error, every time i run gulp build command

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, gulp, serverless-framework

currently i have been asked to look into an application which was developed around in 2017, this project is build to create AS lambda function using serverless framework 1, NodeJs , typescript , and for workflow they had used gulp, now initially i tried to compile the project with specific frameworks which were mentioned in the documentation but after some reading found out that serverless framework 1 is not supported any more so now i have upgraded the serverless framework to 3 and also the latest node js version 21.xx, and then after compiling the project there some syntax error in typescript files which i have fixed and i thought now the project should compile successfully but there is no success because now i am getting compile time errors in the JS files inside dist folder of the project, for example there is a ts file c.ts which does not show any compile time errors but the same transpiled js file c.js is not compiling, am really stuck on how to move forward, can someone please help. I have attached one screenshot of error below which is seen in the JS file, but the same code in typescript is not showing any error.

[image: JS file error in dist folder]

Tried upgrading the version of tools to the latest but it did not work.